# Specifying multiple options in a structure's constructor?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, syntax-error

I tried defining a structure with a custom print function and constructor like so:

```
(defun print-test (a-test stream depth)
       (format stream "#<TEST-STRUCT ~A>" (test-struct-a a-test)))

(defstruct (test-struct (:print-function print-test
                          :constructor create-test
                          (&key a (b a) c)))
       a
       b
       c)
```

But on evaluation I get:

```
Bad defstruct option (:PRINT-FUNCTION PRINT-TEST :CONSTRUCTOR
                      CREATE-TEST (&KEY A B C)).
   [Condition of type CCL::SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

But specifying either keyword alone works just fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [grammar](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm), options must be parenthesized individually.  The `defstruct` form therefore needs to look like this:

```
(defstruct (test-struct (:print-function print-test)
                        (:constructor create-test (&key a (b a) c)))
  a
  b
  c)
```